# How to get last inserted row in sap hana sql trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers, hana

I am creating this sql trigger in SAP HANA and cannot figure out **how to reference the last inserted row**, here is the code for the trigger:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER 
    AFTER INSERT ON TARGET_TABLE 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        CALL SOME_PROCEDURE(:NEWROW.id);
    END;
```

I tried the `REFERENCING NEW ROW` syntax but it seems that it is not supported for `INSERT AFTER` triggers.

Help!

Comment: Additional documentation on HANA Triggers can be found here: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d5a65575191014946db96aaedbef5b/content.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 CREATE TRIGGER TEST_TRIGGER_VAR_UPDATE                   
 AFTER UPDATE ON TARGET                                   
 REFERENCING NEW ROW mynewrow, OLD ROW myoldrow          
 FOR EACH ROW                                             
 BEGIN                                                    
  INSERT INTO SAMPLE_new VALUES(:mynewrow.a, :mynewrow.b); 
  INSERT INTO SAMPLE_old VALUES(:myoldrow.a, :myoldrow.b);
  INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(0, 'trigger');
 END;
```

Comment: I need an INSERT TRIGGER not an UPDATE TRIGGER.

Comment: use INSERT instead of UPDATE

Comment: @tinka what should be query to return autoincrement id for returning inserted row in hana db